# Facebook connect API returning null object in codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I'm having a very strange and weird issue in Facebook connect API inside my Codeigniter 2.1 project. My site has social login feature and all the codes I test in my localhost works perfectly well. But When I upload my project to the hosting server, Facebook connect library returns null object all the times.

I'm using facebook-php-sdk 3.2 and bellow here is the code I that I'm using.

in the config folder I've a file named, facebook.php that contains

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

);
?>
```

I've a library named Fbconnect.php under my library folder. Contains code

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

include (APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/facebook.php');

class Fbconnect extends Facebook {

    /**
     * Configured the facebook object
     */enter code here
    public $user = null;
    public $user_id = null;
    public $fb = false;
    public $fbSession = false;
    public $appkey = 0;

    public function __construct() {
        $ci = & get_instance();
        $ci->config->load('facebook', true);
        $config = $ci->config->item('facebook');
        parent::__construct($config);
        $this->user_id = $this->getUser();
        $me = null;
        if ($this->user_id) {
            try {
                $me = $this->api('/me');
                $this->user = $me;
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
            }
        }
    }

}

?>
```

and below here is my controller's code

```
    public function fb_login()
    {
    $this->load->library('fbconnect');
    $user_data = array(
        'redirect_uri' => actionLink("signup", 'social', 'Facebook'),
        'scope' => 'email'
    );

    redirect($this->fbconnect->getLoginUrl($user_data));

    }
```

I've created a helper function named actionLink, here is it's code

```
function actionLink($controller = '', $action = '', $param = '')
{
    $url = base_url();
    if (strlen($controller) > 0) {
        $url .= "$controller";
        if (strlen($action) > 0) {
            $url .= "/$action";
            if (strlen($param) > 0) {
                $url .= "/$param";
            }
        }
    }

return $url;
```

}

Please Help.

Comment: Any error/exception catched ? Are you testing that code on public url (not localhost.., but domain added at your FB app details) ?  Set at FB configs - 'cookie' => true

Comment: Yes. Domain is added to my FB app details. Every thing working. The redirection, authentication, except it returns a null Facebook user.

Comment: Hi @MahmudurRahmanShibly, I also faced the same problem. I made use of codeigniter's logs to find out the root cause of problem. Anyways, since `error_log($e);` is being used, you can check if any error has occurred from you site's error log file. Just let me know if something is recorded. I'll tell you what to do next if no error is logged.

Comment: Thank you @elavarasan lee. But no error is logged. Please provide me the solution. I'll be grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Signup.php** replace line nos. 37 to 46 with the following: `//inside function social($userType = 'Web')`
**1**. Try Solution No.1 Just to make sure that its working but its not genral, It's specific to Facebook.
**2**. Solution No.2 is same as what you have done but in CI's Way :)

---

**Solution No. 1**:

```
$this->load->library('fbconnect');
$socialId = $this->fbconnect->getSocialId();
$this->data['social_id'] = $socialId;
$email = $this->fbconnect->getEmail();
$this->data['email'] = $email;
$name = $this->fbconnect->getName();
$this->data['name'] = $name;
$this->data['url'] = $userType;
```

---

**Solution No. 2**:

```
$className = $userType . "SocialService";
$this->load->library($className);
$socialId = $this->$className->getSocialId();
$this->data['social_id'] = $socialId;
$email = $this->$className->getEmail();
$this->data['email'] = $email;
$name = $this->$className->getName();
$this->data['name'] = $name;
$this->data['url'] = $userType;
```

Actually Your main problem is in **FacebookSocialService.php**. **You are trying to call a private method within a public method in an incorrect way**. That's the reason you are not able to fetch any details. Solution for that is as follows: 
Inside your public methods

```
public function getSomeData()
{
   $fbSocialService = new FacebookSocialService();
   $some_fb_data = $fbSocialService->getFacebook()->user['some_fb_data'];
   return $some_fb_data;
}
```

- But rather than doing this, You can just make the private method as public. ;) (Just kidding, but its very quick fix) :P

Comment: Thank you very much sire :) I'll check it and if it still not work, I'll post my controller code. Thank you again for being so responsive :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: Still no luck. Same old thing. I guess it is either the cURL or the ssl related issue. It seems that I can't post my controller code here :( either can't answer my own question. Can you please provide me your mail address ? I'll mail you the controller class.

Comment: mailed you :) Please check your inbox.

Comment: Got it... I've replied to you.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'll mail you after testing it. Thank you again :)